# What is the correct way to set a listener to a fragment from an "independent" manager class?

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener

Suppose I have an Activity or a Fragment that uses a *manager* class which dislpays a `DialogFragment`, and that *manager* class needs to listen to some of the `DialogFragment` events.

What is the correct way to set a listener to the `DialogFragment` from the *manager* class, without depending on the Activity or Fragment that is using it?

---

`Activity` ---uses---> `Manager` ---displays---> `DialogFragment`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an Interface listener implement that listener on your manager class and pass the reference of that Listener interface to your dialog class whenever you click it will call the manager class method. Example -

```
    public interface ICallbackListener {
void onCallbackListener();
}

public class ManagerClass implement ICallbackListener{

@Override
public void onCallbackListener(){
// do whatever you want to do.....
}

// pass this method to your dialog....
public void getListner(){
return this;
}
}

// just a demo 
public class CustomDialog extent Dialog{
ICallbackListener listener;
public CustomDialog(ICallbackListener listener){
this.listener = listener;}

// so from where you want to send data just call this
// listener.onCallbackListener();

}
```

Comment: Hi, @lucifer. Thank you for your contribution, but that is not a safe way to do it. If the system kills the app while it is in background, when it recreates it the next time the user opens it, there will be no more reference to the listener.

Comment: So in this case When app recreates again then you must be creating that dialog from some activity or fragment at that time of creation you can pass the reference of that listener from the manager class.

Comment: Android can recreate the fragment by itself, without depending on us to do it.

Comment: If you want to preserve states then go for ViewModel instead of callback hell.